# ETL tools with connectors to [1c] : ERP

Tags: etl, erp, 1c

I am trying to identify ETL tools that have out of the box connectors to connect to the SQL Server Database that is backend DB of [1c]:ERP . This is to fetch data , enable CDC etc to ingest data to a data lake for analytics and machine learning. I checked cloud provider services like ADF , AWS Glue etc but they dont seem to have. Please guide on how to establish either batch data connectivity(ODBC) or real time APIs to the back end SQL server DB of [1c] :ERP

I am still in research phase trying to identify the right tool with connectors and went through documentations of tools like ADF , AWS Glue , Talend but yet to find any reference of a connector to [1c] : ERP

Answer (score 0):

1C has complex SQL data structure with automated name of tables and data fields. If you look at 1C sql tables you will see something like this[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJOZl.png). It is not easy to map SQL fields directly to 1C objects and hence to extract data to other ETL tools directly from SQL. It will be much easier to write a native 1C built in procedures that extracts data from 1C to an acceptable format (CSV, DAT, txt, etc files), or develop microservices for data transfer.